# how to procees dos snort rule with captured packet

Tags: snort, denial-of-service

alert tcp $HOME_NET any -> $HOME_NET 80 (flags: S; msg:"Possible TCP DoS"; flow: stateless;threshold: type both, track by_src, count 70, seconds 10; sid:10001;rev:1;)

Comment: this is a dos attack and above rule is used ofr dos attack

Answer (score 2):

Refer to link : http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node35.html

[image]

Example:
[image]

Image source : http://kangmyounghun.blogspot.com/2017/01/snort-threshold.html

Comment: Hi Mr. Kang I am just making my project for only stop dos attack using snort rule but I didn't know how to write code to match the coming packets  with this rule and how it gets triggerd .any code related help for matching

Comment: @SouravTathgur Refer to link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579701/what-is-difference-between-syn-flood-and-port-scan-attack/43589682#43589682

Comment: that suggestion help me but i want to know how the rule will be triggered when the attack occur mean what to write in code to trigger in rule when attack occur